# How to check if a directory contains a .pdf file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, pdf

A lot of people send me their invoices and they are almost always .pdf files.  I have a limited attention span and so have written some ruby code to save me having to look at them.  It would help if my bit of Ruby code would look into a folder and, if there was an invoice there, return the name of the file and its path.  The thing is that the people who send me their invoices are very annoying and name their files in the worst way. For example, one of them has given me an invoice called "Invoice_Cost_Centre_6454537.pdf". I can't be expected to remember that sort of name.  However they are always (almost) .pdfs.
I was taking to Ruby about it and she said this,

```
File.exist?('test\Invoice_Cost_Centre_61356.pdf')
#=> true

File.exists?('test\*.pdf')
#=> false
```

I have had a look at the docs for the `File` class and thought that `File.fnmatch?(pattern, path)` might be a solution but I couldn't get it to work.

I would appreciate any help. I'm fairly new to Ruby so please keep your sentences short.

Comment: "I couldn't get it to work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @desdinthewater : I suggest to use forward slashes as path separator. It spares you to consider cases where a backslash is used to escape the subsequent character. Aside from this, `Dir.glob("directory/*.pdf")` would return you an Array of all names ending in _.pdf_ in this directory.

Comment: That's a very long-winded explanation for such a small question :-)

Comment: What can I say?  I'm a windbag in lockdown

Comment: Thank-you all  I found ndnenkov's answer thought provoking. - And I have spend a bit of time reading through the Directory Class notes.  In the end, @user1934428 's answer was simplest, and getting an array back is quite useful.  In answer to Jorg W Mittag, I wasn't sure that I was on the right track ( this was confirmed by ndnenkov and user1934428) and as Stefan has pointed out, I can be a bit long winded.  Answering all your questions to your complete satisfaction could have taken considerable time.  Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 1):

`File.exists?` checks if a file with that path exists verbatim.

`File.fnmatch?` checks if a path matches a given pattern, but doesn't actually look up that path.

Instead you could `Dir['test/*.pdf'].empty?`

Comment: Since the user wants to check for existence, it's probably `Dir['test/*.pdf'].any?` (or `Dir['*.pdf', base: 'test'].any?` to separate directory and file pattern)